# Unity Animation Controller: Is the "atomic" attribute in 4.6.3 the same as the "has exit time" attribute in 5.0?

Tags: unity, animation

I'm viewing a tutorial based on Unity 5.0. In this version, I see an option whose name is: `Has Exit Time`:

[image: example from Unity 5.0]

But on my Unity, version 4.6.3, I don't have this option. Instead I have an option called `Atomic`.

[image: example from Unity 4.6]

My guess is that these options mean the same thing. That is, if this box is checked, then the controller should finish playing this state before moving to a new state. But I'm not sure here. If my guess is wrong, which option is equivalent to `Has Exit Time` in Unity 4.6.3 ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No, they're two different things.

`HasExitTime`: if a transition has this option activated, it means that it will jump to the new state after a certain `ExitTime` (1 ExitTime = 1 Full Animation clip) has passed. If it's disabled, then that transition will be executed only if certain conditions will be met (added in the `Conditions` list) - until then, the current state will loop indefinitely.

`Atomic`: this has been changed in Unity 5 as the `Interruption Source` setting option - the old `Atomic` is equivalent to the `None` option, and it means that the transition cannot be interrupted by other conditions triggering other transitions, so it will be completed no matter what else happens.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I'm testing it looks like this may be a different setting they've added, and what used to be called "atomic" is in that new Settings menu (note the word Settings with an arrow, just below Has Exit Time). It looks like now you might want to look in that menu and set Interruption Source to Current State; clear as mud >:(

Also, every transition I've tested needs "Has Exit Time" off, so I'm not sure why it defaults on.